# Format ListView based on contents

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I have a ListView that has two columns, one for a zone name and then a corresponding OK/NOK in the second column.

I wish to format the second column based on whether it contains OK or NOK.

I could do this quite easily with a GridView by using something similar to the following, I may be wrong, but from what I can see a ListView doesn't have the same option.

```
protected void grdZoneStatus_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Cells[1].Text == "NOK")
    {
        e.Row.Cells[1].ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

So basically, how should I go about formatting a cell based on its contents within a ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a ListView called *lvTest* which two columns of which the second one is the relevant, this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lvTest.Items) 
{
    if(item.SubItems[1].Text == "OK") 
        item.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    else 
        item.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

should do the trick.